# How to proxy local WP uploads folder to live site

Tags: uploads, redirect, htaccess, customization

**Stack:**

MAMP PRO on OSX 10.11.5 (El Cap)

**Scenario:**

I'm developing a site locally, and there is already a live version of the site online. Rather than download all 4gb of the *uploads* folder, I'd like to have my local site just load the images from the live URL instead.

**Concept:**

Through lots of searching, I've found many variations of `.haccess` files you can use to accomplish this. My favorite ones use the following conditions:

1. Checks that you are on the dev server first (`HTTP_HOST`)
2. Checks that the requested URL is in wp-content/uploads (`REQUEST_URI`)
3. Checks that the requested URL does not exist locally (file or directory via `REQUEST_FILENAME`)
4. If these pass, then execute the rewrite rule.

**Code:**

Here's my `.htaccess` snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wp-content/uploads/
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^LOCALSITE\.dev$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://LIVESITE.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,P]
</IfModule>
```

FOR THE LIFE OF ME I CANNOT GET THIS TO WORK RIGHT

I've run as many tests as I can think of, and have verified that mod_rewrite is **ON** in MAMP. I've read more htaccess documentation that I care for, and I'm going in circles now.

**Test:**

One of my tests leaves me confused. Here's what I did:

1. Create a page in WordPress with 2 images in the content.

   - "Image A" exists on my local machine only
   - "Image B" exists on the LIVE site only, but is using my local hostname in the URL
2. Image A shows up, Image B gets a 404 error (as expected)
3. Add the `.htaccess` snippet after WordPress stuff
4. Nothing changes
5. But if I comment out all the `RewriteCond` statements, Image A 404's because it is the only one which actually gets rewritten with the LIVE URL. It doesn't exist there so yeah it 404's. But Image B's URL has *not* been rewritten and it 404's also.

**Disclaimer:** It's 4am

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

So I discovered the answer after reading through my question after I posted it....

**The htaccess rules need to go BEFORE the WordPress rules**

There you have it. That was the problem this entire time.

I'm going to bed.